# Apache Kafka config/producer.properties

Tags: apache-kafka, producer-consumer

I want to copy kafka data to hadoop. How can i do configuration of producer.properties file. Kafka data format is .avro file.

```
metadata.broker.list
request.required.acks
producer.type
serializer.class
```

Comment: Please take a look to :https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs

Comment: i dont use confluent tool. I want to move just pure Kafka. As i know, i can use producer to create topic and this topic can stored in more than one server. So i want to keep log file with copy in kafka server and hadoop log file system. How can i do that with these configuration  ?